# How to install `gtk+2.0` on Debian Sid?

Tags: debian, gtk

In order to compile a software (`https://github.com/bnordli/rftg/wiki/Compiling-on-Linux`) I first need to install the `gtk+2.0` package. But I cannot find it with `aptitude search`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install `gtk+2.0` package you should run:

```
apt-get install gtk2.0
```

The development files for the GTK+ library can be installed through :

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: The `configure` step mentioned explicitly a `gtk+2.0` package. I should have thought better and search for a `gtk2` dev-lib. Sorry, I was tired. Thanks for this obvious answer!